# Preventing Angular material from loading Roboto font from google

Tags: angular, angular-material

How do i prevent angular material design from injecting

`https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500&display=swap`

and

`https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons`

as links into the `<head>` element?

Answer (score 2):

Roboto is loaded via index.html file and its the default font type shipped with Angular Material Design.

If you would like to change it you need to perform typography customisation which is explained in this [guide here](https://material.angular.io/guide/typography).

Comment: In addition to this, [here's a great video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g0GhiKMacsE) that explains how to go about customising the typography of your Angular Material components.

Comment: Does not seem to work though. It's still loading roboto and material icons from google.